# Given three independent events $A,B,C$, is $I_A+2I_B$ independent of $I_C$?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and $A,B,C\in \mathcal{F}$ are independent. Is $I_A+2I_B$ independent of $I_C$?

$I_A,I_B,I_C$ are indicator random variables.

I started by computing $\sigma(I_A+2I_B)$ and $\sigma(I_C)$.

$$
\sigma(I_A+2I_B)=\{ \phi,A,B,A\cup B,A\cap B,(A\cup B)^C,(A\cap B)^C,A\cap B^C,A^C \cap B,A^C\cup B,A\cup B^C,(A\cup B)^C\cup (A\cap B),(A\cup B)\cap (A\cap B)^C,\Omega\}
$$

$$
\sigma(I_C)=\{\phi,C,C^C,\Omega\}
$$

Now, it remains to verify that for any $X\in \sigma(I_A+2I_B)$, $Y\in \sigma(I_C)$
$$P(X\cap Y)=P(X)P(Y)$$

But, this seems to be a very tedious task. Is there a simpler way to tackle this problem?

Comment: If you want to argue in terms of sigma-algebras, then just note that by assumption $\sigma(I_C)$ is independent of $\sigma(I_A,I_B)$. Then, since $\sigma(I_A+2I_B)\subseteq\sigma(I_A,I_B)$, we also have $\sigma(I_C)$ is independent of $\sigma(I_A+2I_B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for alternative route:

If random variable $X$ only takes values in finite set $S$ and random
variable $Y$ only in finite set $T$ then checking independence comes
to checking $P\left(X=s\wedge Y=t\right)=P\left(X=s\right)P\left(Y=t\right)$
for $s\in S$ and $t\in T$.

In your case the sets $S$ and $T$ can be taken quite small, so the verification will not be tedious.

Comment: Thank you! Your hint worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. You are very welcome.